# Is there a difference between "apt-get install kdm" and "apt-get install kubuntu-desktop"?

Tags: installation, apt, kubuntu, kde

My question's title is pretty straightforward.  Is there a difference between installing KDE with the command "**`apt-get install kdm`**" or "**`apt-get install kubuntu-desktop`**"?

I'm installing Penguy OS on a virtual drive on my Macbook Pro, and I understand it is based on Ubuntu.  I already know that I like KDE more than the alternative desktops available.

I just want to know which command to type once the installation finishes in order to get KDE on there.

And just in case it's questioned, I downloaded Kubuntu but it did not get along with VirtualBox which is why I'm going for Penguy.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop` ([kubuntu-desktop [image: Install kubuntu-desktop]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/kubuntu-desktop)) -This is the recommended metapackage to install; the full Kubuntu installation, with all the Kubuntu recommended packages. This includes OpenOffice, Kontact, Konversation, amaroK, K3B, and others.

`sudo apt-get install kdm` ([kdm [image: Install kdm]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/kdm)) -This will install the following packages: kde-wallpapers-default, kde-workspace-kgreet-plugins, kdm, libkworkspace4abi2, libqimageblitz4.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!  I'll do the kubuntu one

Comment: Source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingKDE

Answer (score 4):

**KDM** is a graphical login interface just like [GDM](http://projects.gnome.org/gdm/), [Lxdm](http://wiki.lxde.org/en/LXDM), and [LightDM](https://launchpad.net/lightdm).

KDM can be installed by running the command below in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install kdm
```

- Or by clicking this: [kdm [image: Install kdm]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/kdm)

Now, **Kubuntu-Desktop** is the actual desktop environment, such as [Unity](http://unity.ubuntu.com/), [Gnome](http://www.gnome.org/), [Xfce](http://www.xfce.org/), and [Lxde](http://lxde.org/).

Kubuntu-desktop can be installed by running the command below in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

- Or by clicking this: [kubuntu-desktop [image: Install kubuntu-desktop]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/kubuntu-desktop)